# Why is my js code not capturing the margin-right value from id="article_toggle"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function articleToggle() {

  if (document.getElementById('article_toggle').style.marginRight == 0) {
    document.getElementById('article_toggle').style.marginRight = "400";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('article_toggle').style.marginRight = "0";
  }

  alert(toggle);

}
```

```css
article {
  position: fixed;
  top: 170px;
  right: 0;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 40px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#article_toggle {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<article id="article_toggle">

  <div onclick="articleToggle()">
    <a href="#">
      <p class="articlebar_title articlebar_toggle">Article Index</p>
    </a>
  </div>

</article>
```

I have a right sidebar menu that has a tab on the left side. When the menu is closed, the tab should be aligned to the right edge of the screen exposing the tab, but the menu should be hidden. When I click on the tab, the margin-right should change from -400px to 0, the menu with the tab attached should slide out to the left the width of the menu. And when I click again on the tab, the margin-right should change from 0 to -400px closing the menu.

So, where am I going wrong in my code? I do not want to use jquery.

Thanks.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do

Comment: You missed the 'px' so your question is non-reproductible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function articleToggle() {
    if (parseFloat(document.getElementById('article_toggle').style.marginRight) == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('article_toggle').style.marginRight = "50px";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('article_toggle').style.marginRight = "0";
    }

    }
```

```css
  article {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    width: 400px;
    bottom: 40px;
    background: #ffffff;
    }

    #article_toggle {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
 <article id="article_toggle">

        <div onclick="articleToggle()"><a href="#"><p class="articlebar_title articlebar_toggle">Article Index</p></a>
        </div>

    </article>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. All you did was to add the parseFloat?

Comment: nope, you need to speciafy unite for marginRight attrbute, `document.getElementById('article_toggle').style.marginRight` e.g `"50px"; "50em" , etc...`

Comment: Yes, yes. I did see that, too, and I did incorporate that.